# Converting String symbol into char

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I am implementing an monoalphabetic substitution algorithm. Keys and values ​​are stored in the HashMap, and as a parameter of the input string using a variable of StringBuffer class type:

```
public class Mono {
    private StringBuffer source;
    private Map<String, String> alphabet;

public Mono(String source) {
    this.source = new StringBuffer(source);
    alphabet = new HashMap<>();
    alphabet.put("a", "f");
    alphabet.put( //... etc.
}

public StringBuffer startEncrypt() {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
            for (Map.Entry entry : alphabet.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getKey().toString().equals(source.charAt(i))) {
                    source.setCharAt(i, entry.getValue().toString());
                }
            }
        }

        return source;
    }
}
```

I encountered a problem converting string to char here: `source.setCharAt(i, entry.getValue().toString());`

So, my question is how to do it? Or is there another, better way of replacing characters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `charAt(0)` to get the first character of a string... just like you're already doing for your key. Note that if you use a parameterized `Map.Entry` instead of the raw type, you won't need the `toString` call either:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : alphabet.entrySet()) {
    // TODO: Should this be source.charAt(i)?
    if (entry.getKey().equals(source.charAt(0))) {
        source.setCharAt(i, entry.getValue().charAt(0));
    }
}
```

That said, if all your strings are really just a single character, why don't you use a `Map<Character, Character>`? Additionally, iterating over *all* the entries in the map is inefficient and almost certainly *not* what you want to do. I suspect you *actually* want something like:

```
private final Map<Character, Character> mappings;

public String substitute(String input) {
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; < chars.length; i++) {
        Character sub = mapping.get(chars[i]);
        if (sub != null) {
            chars[i] = sub;
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: `Should this be source.charAt(i)?` yes, you are right - fixed. I haven't fully acquainted with Collections Framework yet, so thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
entry.getValue().toString().chartAt(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure will that fit your needs but I would go like:

```
public class Mono {
    private StringBuffer source;
    private Map<Character, Character> alphabet;

    public Mono(String source) {
        this.source = new StringBuffer(source);
        alphabet = new HashMap<>();
        alphabet.put('a', 'f');
        alphabet.put( //... etc.
    }

    public StringBuffer startEncrypt() {
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
            for (Character key : alphabet.keySet()) {
                if (source.charAt(0) == key) {
                    source.setCharAt(i, alphabet.get(key));
                }
            }
        }

        return source;
    }
}
```

It's more readable and you don't need any type conversion. Simpler is better :)